# are these two finite groups with different presentation isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, gap

Consider two groups $$\langle x,y \, | \, x^4=y^5=1 ,yxy=x \rangle$$ and $$ \langle a,b \, | \, a^{10}=1,b^2=a^5,aba=b \rangle.$$

I think they are isomorphic, but I can't show it, it will be great if you help about this.

I have the software GAP, if you tell how can I show it with GAP, it will be enough.

thanks.

I did big mistake when I was typing the second group, I edit it now, please excuse me.

actually second group is $Dic_4$,Dicyclic group of order 20.

Comment: The first group is the semi-direct product of $Z_5 = \langle y \rangle$ by $Z_4 = \langle x \rangle$, with $Z_4$ acting on $Z_5$ via $xyx^{-1} = y^{-1}$. This group has order 20. In the second group, you have $bab^{-1} = a^{-1}$. Then $b^5 a b^{-5} = a^{-1}$. Using $b^5 = a^2$, we find $a^2 = 1$. It follows easily that this group is $Z_5 \times Z_2 \cong Z_{10}$. Thus the two groups have different orders.

Comment: @Keith: you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: My answer above is not applicable to the question as it has now been edited.

Comment: There are only three nonabelian groups of order 20. You can check them out at http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_20 and see which ones match yours.

Comment: Lots of info about groups of order 20 at http://www.fredonia.edu/department/math/facultypages/straight/groups/pdf/groups20.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there was a question of how to do it in GAP:

You first create the two groups:

```
f:=FreeGroup("x","y");
rels:=ParseRelators(f,"x4,y5,yxy=x");
g1:=f/rels;
f2:=FreeGroup("a","b");
rels2:=ParseRelators(f2,"a10,b2=a5,aba=b");
g2:=f2/rels2;
```

Then (this implicitly uses that the groups are finite, it will not necessarily work for infinite groups):

```
gap> IsomorphismGroups(g1,g2);
[ x, y ] -> [ b*a^31, a^24 ]
```

returns one (not necessarily the nicest, or always the same) isomorphism (or `fail` if none exists). If you want to try all possibilities, you could use

```
SetReducedMultiplication(g2);
SetReducedMultiplication(g1);
```

to force immediate reduction of word expressions (otherwise GAP builds up products and never reduces) and then use (to get all isomorphisms, multiply one particular one with all possible automorphisms of the image):

```
a:=AutomorphismGroup(g2);
all:=List(Elements(a),x->iso*x);
```

and find (this is for me the nicest) the isomorphism $x\mapsto b$, $y\mapsto a^2$.

Comment: Also, for small groups of orders where identification in the small groups library is available, one could just call `IdGroup` for both groups and compare the result, in case there is no need in the actual isomorphism - in situations when you care about performance, ask GAP to return just what is sufficient, but not for much more!

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=\langle x,y \ | \ x^4=y^5=1, \ yxy=x\rangle$ and $H=\langle a,b \ | \ a^{10}=1, b^2=a^5, aba=b\rangle.$  Note that $x^2\in Z(G)$.

Define $\phi\colon H\to G$ by \begin{align} \phi(a) &= x^2 y, \\ \phi(b) &= x. \end{align}
Then 
\begin{align}
\phi(a^5)&=(x^2 y)^5=x^{10}y^5=x^2=\phi(b^2),\\
\phi(aba)&=(x^2 y)x (x^2 y) = yxy = x = \phi(b),\\
\phi(b^2 a)&=y.
\end{align}
Thus $\phi$ is a well-defined surjective homomorphism of groups.

We need to verify injectivity.  Note that if we knew that $G$ has order 20, then we are done, but by OP we only know that $H$ is order 20; surjectivity forces $G$ finite, at least.  So we either verify that $G$ has order (at least) 20, or verify that $\ker(\phi)$ is trivial.  I'll do the latter, since then we don't even need to know or check that either group is finite.

For any integers $i,j$ we have $$ \phi(a^i b^j) = x^{2i}y^i x^j = x^{2i+j} y^{(-1)^j i}.$$  So for this to be the identity we have $i\equiv 0\bmod 5$ and $2i+j\equiv 0\bmod 4$.  So we may write $i=5k$ for $k=0,1$ and then $10k+j\equiv 2k+j\equiv 0\bmod 4$.  Solving, we get the only solutions with $0\leq j<4$ are $k=0, j=0$ and $k=1,j=2$.  In both cases, $a^i b^j = a^{5k}b^j=a^{10} = 1$.  Thus $\ker(\phi)=1$ and the homomorphism is injective.

Thus we have exhibited a group isomorphism, and $G\cong H$.

Comment: Why from a *surjective* homomorphism of groups would follow they are isomorphic? This is grossly false in general.

Comment: @Timbuc The key words you're missing are *finite of the same order*.  You could show injectivity directly with another straightforward calculation, but it's unnecessary if you know the groups are finite of the same order.  I'll edit that to be clearer.

Comment: Where did you even hint about **same order** in your original post?? Of course, you can write as much as you want about what *I missed* **after** you edit your original post ...

Comment: @Timbuc The OP specifies that $H$ is a dicyclic group of order 20.  Since the homomorphism is surjective, $G$ must be finite as well.  That it is also of order 20 seems to have just been everyone's common assumption, and I suppose technically that needs to be justified.

Comment: @zi Yes, but after the question itself, the comments and the answer have been so edited there is no much point to continue to dwell with this as I'm not even sure what the original question was. Thanks.

Comment: @Timbuc I've edited in the proper details for the injectivity, thus removing any need for assumptions of order or even finiteness for either group.